# drupal7 : db_select node with multiple values field

Tags: 7, database

I have a problem with db_select, i want to return a node per row for each value of the multiple values field :

- node_1 : value_1_of_the_multiple_values_field
- node_1 : value_2_of_the_multiple_values_field
- node_1 : value_2_of_the_multiple_values_field
- ...

here is my code with the join it only return a node linked to the values of the field :

```
$query = db_select('node', 'n')
->extend('PagerDefault');
```

// Add join with multiple values field ( a date )

```
$query->join('field_data_field_date_programme_culturel', 'fdfdpc', 'fdfdpc.entity_id = n.nid');
$query->fields('n');
```

any idea please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've often struggled with the join methods in the D7 database layer. When I've needed to use a join, I've just used `db_query()` and passed it my SQL string. I know that when calling the `join()` method, you must already have the object initialised. So:

```
$query = db_select('node', 'n');
$query->join(field_data_field_date_programme_culturel', 'fdfdpc', 'fdfdpc.entity_id = n.nid');
```

and you already have it like this so I don't think that's the issue. I'd suggest using `db_query($sql)`.